# In golang, why does `a := []int32("hello")` work but not `a := []int("hello")`?

Tags: string, go, type-conversion, slice

The tile is my question. In Go, why does `a := []int32("hello")` work but not `a := []int("hello")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the spec allows converting a `string` value to a `rune` slice (`[]rune`), and `rune` is an [alias](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types) to `int32` (they are one and the same). This is what the first [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)
 does:

> Converting a value of a string type to a slice of runes type yields a slice containing the individual Unicode code points of the string.

Basically a `string` => `[]rune` conversion decodes the UTF-8 bytes of the text (this is how Go stores strings in memory) to Unicode code points (`rune`s).

And the spec does not allow converting a `string` to an `int` slice, so the second is a compile-time error.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. So it's all due to the spec.